# How to create a block showing the sliding gallery of just 1 of the galleries?

Tags: blocks, views, media

I am running a site (D7.43, jQuery 1.10), with the jollyany (bootstrap) theme as the basis. Among other things the site has several image galleries, generated through Views. The set up is as follows: There is a content type called Projects, where you first enter a square picture, then any number of photos that form the actual gallery.

On the galleries page (have a look: http://wixschool.net/image-gallery) Views and masonry then generate an overview of all galleries (projects) that have been created, showing the square image + with mouseover and button etc. Click on one of them, and you are presented with that individual gallery, for example: http://wixschool.net/image-gallery/peace-mile-run-battersea-park.

What I want to do now is take an individual gallery, and show that on a single page somewhere as a block. That means I want to click on a link, and end up on a page that has the slider of that gallery as one part of its content, and skipping the masonry overview.

I can and have create(d) a block, but then end up with that block showing the masonry gallery (even if filtered to just the one gallery I want). I then have to click on the gallery, which opens a new full node (page) with just that gallery and nothing else.

I assume its a [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) thing, contextual filters? Any help / instructions / solutions very very welcome!

**Edit**: the template that runs the Image Gallery (Project) page is `node--projects.tpl.php`:

```
<?php
    /**
     * @file
     * jollyany's theme implementation to display a single Portfolio node.
     */
    global $base_url; 
    global $image_default; 

    // Grabs the firsts image path and sets $imagePath.
    $imagePath = $image_default;
    if(isset($node->field_image['und'])) {
        $imagePath = file_create_url($node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']); 
    }

    $next = jollyany_pagination($node, 'n');
    $prev = jollyany_pagination($node, 'p');

    if ($next != NULL) { 
      $next_url = url('node/' . $next, array('absolute' => TRUE));
    }

    if ($prev != NULL) { 
      $prev_url = url('node/' . $prev, array('absolute' => TRUE));
    }

    $image_slide = "";

    if ($items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_gallery')) {
      if (count($items) == 1) {
        $image_slide = 'false';
      }
      elseif (count($items) > 1) {
        $image_slide = 'true';
      }
    }

    $img_count = 0;
    $counter = count($items);

    $termid = arg(2);
?>

<?php if (!$page) : ?>
    <?php if( !empty($termid) ) : ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
    <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="portfolio_item">
            <div class="entry">
                <img src="<?php echo $imagePath; ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="magnifier">
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <a class="st btn btn-default" rel="bookmark" href="<?php echo $node_url; ?>"><?php print theme_get_setting('project_text_button'); ?></a>
                        <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php if( !empty($termid) ) : ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else :?>
    <div class="row">
    <?php if(isset($node->field_layout['und']) && $node->field_layout['und'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name == 'Sidebar') :?>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 single-portfolio">
                <div class="col-sm-7 padding-left-0">
                    <?php if(isset($node->field_video['und']) && !empty($node->field_video['und'][0]['value'])) :?>
                        <div class="portfolio_item">
                            <div class="entry">
                                <?php print $node->field_video['und'][0]['value']; ?>
                                <div class="post-type">
                                    <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php elseif(isset($node->field_audio['und']) && !empty($node->field_audio['und'][0]['value'])) :?>
                        <div class="portfolio_item">
                            <div class="entry">
                                <?php print $node->field_audio['und'][0]['value']; ?>
                                <div class="post-type">
                                    <i class="fa fa-music"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php elseif($image_slide != '') : ?>
                        <div id="aboutslider" class="flexslider clearfix">
                            <ul class="slides">
                                <?php while ($img_count < $counter) { ?>
                                    <?php /*?><li><img src="<?php echo image_style_url('image_650x312',$node->field_gallery['und'][$img_count]['uri']); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li><?php */?>
                                   <li><img src="<?php echo file_create_url($node->field_gallery['und'][$img_count]['uri']); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li>


                                <?php $img_count++; } ?>
                                <?php echo $img_count; ?>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="aboutslider-shadow">
                            <span class="s1"></span>
                        </div>
                    <?php else :?>
                        <div class="portfolio_item">
                            <div class="entry">
                                <img src="<?php echo $imagePath; ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="magnifier">
                                    <div class="buttons">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $imagePath; ?>" class="sf" title="" data-gal="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></a>
                                        <a class="st" rel="bookmark" target="_blank" href="http://caoutchouc.co.uk"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></a>
                                        <a class="sg" rel="bookmark" target="_blank" href="http://caoutchouc.co.uk"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 padding-right-0">
                    <?php /*?><div class="title">
                        <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
                    </div><?php */?>
                    <?php
                        // Hide comments, tags, and links now so that we can render them later.
                        hide($content['field_live_demo']);
                        hide($content['field_tags']);
                        hide($content['field_category']);
                        hide($content['field_skill']);
                        hide($content['field_image']);
                        hide($content['field_gallery']);
                        hide($content['field_audio']);
                        hide($content['field_video']);
                        hide($content['field_layout']);
                        hide($content['links']);
                        hide($content['comments']);
                        print render($content);
                    ?>
                    <?php /*?><?php if(theme_get_setting('showsocial')): ?>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="social-2 f-left a2a_kit">
                            <a class="a2a_dd" href="http://www.addtoany.com/share_save"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
                            <a class="a2a_button_linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                            <a class="a2a_button_pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
                            <a class="a2a_button_google_plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                            <a class="a2a_button_twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a class="a2a_button_facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?><?php */?>
                    <div class="product_details">
                        <?php /*?><h3><?php print t('Gallery Details'); ?></h3><?php */?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php /*?><li><strong><?php print t('Added by'); ?>:</strong> <?php print strip_tags($name); ?></li>
                            <?php if(isset($node->field_live_demo['und'])) : ?>
                                <li><strong><?php print t('Live demo'); ?>:</strong> <a href="<?php print $node->field_live_demo['und'][0]['value']; ?>"><?php print $node->field_live_demo['und'][0]['value']; ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if(isset($node->field_category['und'])) : ?>
                                <li><strong><?php print t('Category'); ?>:</strong> <?php print jollyany_format_comma_field('field_category', $node); ?></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if(isset($node->field_skill['und'])) : ?>
                                <li><strong><?php print t('Skill'); ?>:</strong> <?php print jollyany_format_comma_field('field_skill', $node); ?></li>
                            <?php endif; ?><?php */?>
                            <br /><span class="smallprint"><?php print t('Date posted'); ?>: <?php print format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'd M, Y'); ?></span>
                            <?php /*?><?php if(isset($node->field_tags['und'])) : ?>
                                <li><strong><?php print t('Tags'); ?>:</strong> <?php print jollyany_format_comma_field('field_tags', $node); ?></li>
                            <?php endif; ?><?php */?>
                        </ul>               
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <?php if($page && module_exists('prev_next')): ?>   
                    <div class="next_prev text-center">
                        <ul class="pager">
                            <?php if(isset($prev_url)) : ?>
                                <li class="previous">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $prev_url; ?>">← Previous</a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if(isset($next_url)) : ?>
                                <li class="next">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $next_url; ?>">Next →</a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>         

            </div>

    <?php else :?>

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 single-portfolio">
                <div class="full_portfolio">
                <div class="backtogalleries"><a href="/image-gallery" target="_self" class="btn-primary btn-xs">back to gallery overview</a></div>
                    <?php if(isset($node->field_video['und']) && !empty($node->field_video['und'][0]['value'])) :?>
                        <div class="portfolio_item">
                            <div class="entry">
                                <?php print $node->field_video['und'][0]['value']; ?>
                                <div class="post-type">
                                    <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php elseif(isset($node->field_audio['und']) && !empty($node->field_audio['und'][0]['value'])) :?>
                        <div class="portfolio_item">
                            <div class="entry">
                                <?php print $node->field_audio['und'][0]['value']; ?>
                                <div class="post-type">
                                    <i class="fa fa-music"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php elseif($image_slide != '') : ?>
                        <div id="aboutslider" class="flexslider clearfix">
                            <ul class="slides">
                                <?php while ($img_count < $counter) { ?>
                                   <?php /*?><li><img src="<?php echo image_style_url('image_650x312',$node->field_gallery['und'][$img_count]['uri']); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li><?php */?>
                                   <li><img src="<?php echo file_create_url($node->field_gallery['und'][$img_count]['uri']); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></li>

                                <?php $img_count++; } ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slider-shadow"></div>
                            <?php else :?>
                        <div class="portfolio_item">
                            <div class="entry">
                                <img src="<?php echo $imagePath; ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="magnifier">
                                    <div class="buttons">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $imagePath; ?>" class="sf" title="" data-gal="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></a>
                                        <a class="st" rel="bookmark" target="_blank" href="http://caoutchouc.co.uk"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></a>
                                        <a class="sg" rel="bookmark" target="_blank" href="http://caoutchouc.co.uk"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <div <?php /*?>class="col-lg-12"<?php */?>>
                    <?php /*?><div class="title">
                        <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
                    </div>  <?php */?>
                    <?php
                        // Hide comments, tags, and links now so that we can render them later.
                        hide($content['field_live_demo']);
                        hide($content['field_tags']);
                        hide($content['field_category']);
                        hide($content['field_skill']);
                        hide($content['field_image']);
                        hide($content['field_gallery']);
                        hide($content['field_audio']);
                        hide($content['field_video']);
                        hide($content['field_layout']);
                        hide($content['links']);
                        hide($content['comments']);
                        print render($content);
                    ?>
                    <?php /*?><?php if(theme_get_setting('showsocial')): ?>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="social-2 f-left a2a_kit">
                            <a class="a2a_dd" href="http://www.addtoany.com/share_save"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
                            <a class="a2a_button_linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                            <a class="a2a_button_pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
                            <a class="a2a_button_google_plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                            <a class="a2a_button_twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a class="a2a_button_facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?><?php */?>
                    <div class="product_details">
                        <?php /*?><h3><?php print t('Gallery Details'); ?></h3>
                        <ul><?php */?>

                            <?php /*?><li><strong><?php print t('Added by'); ?>:</strong> <?php print strip_tags($name); ?></li>
                            <?php if(isset($node->field_live_demo['und'])) : ?>
                                <li><strong><?php print t('Live demo'); ?>:</strong> <a href="<?php print $node->field_live_demo['und'][0]['value']; ?>"><?php print $node->field_live_demo['und'][0]['value']; ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if(isset($node->field_category['und'])) : ?>
                                <li><strong><?php print t('Category'); ?>:</strong> <?php print jollyany_format_comma_field('field_category', $node); ?></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if(isset($node->field_skill['und'])) : ?>
                                <li><strong><?php print t('Skill'); ?>:</strong> <?php print jollyany_format_comma_field('field_skill', $node); ?></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <li><?php */?>
                            <br /><span class="smallprint"><?php print t('Date posted'); ?>: <?php print format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'd M, Y'); ?></span>
                            <?php /*?></li>
                            <?php if(isset($node->field_tags['und'])) : ?>
                                <li><strong><?php print t('Tags'); ?>:</strong> <?php print jollyany_format_comma_field('field_tags', $node); ?></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul><?php */?>

                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <?php if($page && module_exists('prev_next')): ?>   
                    <div class="next_prev text-center">
                        <ul class="pager">
                            <?php if(isset($prev_url)) : ?>
                                <li class="previous">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $prev_url; ?>">← Previous</a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if(isset($next_url)) : ?>
                                <li class="next">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $next_url; ?>">Next →</a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>                     

            </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>`
```

Comment: How are the individual galleries created? as a page view?

Comment: As far as I can see the masonry overview is a view, but the actual gallery is a node (the actual page/node/content type instance I add under content), with a template.php turning the pictures into the sliding gallery..

Comment: Unless we can see that template.php code, it would be hard to help. So if you can add it to your Q, that would be helpful.

Comment: have tried to add as code but mucks up the code a bit? Seems OK now :)

Comment: after `global $image_default;` if you add `$node = node_load(16);` upload and overwrite, flush the cache, does it load node's 16 slideshow on all the pages?

Comment: I tried, I get an 'unexpected error' page for all sliders when I do that

Comment: did you use a node # that has a slideshow? I just randomly picked 16

Comment: Ha I did 16 ;) I guess your thinking is this way I can call any individual gallery using a contextual link and the template.. I can see that for a page, but I need the gallery to appear in a block? Help me think this through?

Comment: If it works with a gallery nid, then all you would've to do is copy this code and paste it into your block template file and strip out all the unnecessary stuff.

Comment: This sounds logical but I can't get this to work fully (my bad). Just so I get this straight:
1) in Views I create a block version of my gallery page View
2) I create a block template file named `block--views--projects-block.tpl.php` or similar
3) in that template I copy and paste the same code as node--projects.tpl.php, stripping out unneeded parts
4) in the top of template I put `$node = node_load(node ID);`
?

Comment: I guess I add a contextual filter 'Node ID' to my Projects view block, and then instead of $node = node_load(16); I put something that echoes the Node ID? So that on each page where I show the block it only takes the gallery of the same name? What would that piece of code in the template then look like?

Comment: `So that on each page where I show the block it only takes the gallery of the same name?` If you use `$node = node_load(16);` it will always show the gallery belonging to node 16, isn't that what you want? OR you want to use the nid based on the node you're viewing?

Comment: Yes, the idea is I have a page (basic page node) for each class at the school, I include a block that shows 1 image gallery, only the one that belongs to that class. So if node 'nursery is opened, I would like the block to show image gallery 'nursery', and if node 'year  one' is opened image gallery 'year one'.. So how do I code a Node ID into the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, the idea is I have a page (basic page node) for each class at
>   the school, I include a block that shows 1 image gallery, only the one
>   that belongs to that class. So if node 'nursery is opened, I would
>   like the block to show image gallery 'nursery', and if node 'year one'
>   is opened image gallery 'year one'.. So how do I code a Node ID into
>   the template?

```
<?php

if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  // Get the nid
  $nid = $node->nid;

  $node = node_load($nid);

}


?>
```

This will automatically pass the nid that you're on (have opened).

Comment: No Sssweat. I have upped your answer, but am too newbie for it to count as yet.

Comment: Your script works fine, but I realised now that I should have asked my question a little different, sorry. What I actually need is a piece of code at the top of my block script that looks at the title of the class page I'm on (say /classes/year-one) and then shows the gallery with the same title (e.g. /image-gallery/year-one.

Comment: I have found another way, not as elegant as fully automatically calling the correct gallery based on name of page and name of gallery, but still elegant enough. What I've done: added a field to the gallery content type asking for which class page it belongs to; added a relationship with that field to the block view, added a contextual filter on Nid with that relationship.. Now the block shows up the correct gallery only on the node marked on the gallery creation/edit form..